# Cypher: How to create a relation during loading

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher, load

I am trying to setup my playground database from here https://github.com/tategallery/collection.  I've already setup an artist collection (easy one) and now i am struggling with relation creation on load. Is it possible somehow to create a link in the same time when you create a new node?

`LOAD CSV FROM 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tategallery/collection/master/artwork_data.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Art {id: line[0], accession_number: line[1], artistId: line[4], title: line[5], medium: line[7], creditLine: line[8], year: line[9], width: line[12], height: line[13], depth: line[14], units: line[15], thumbnailUrl: line[18], url: line[19]}) + somehow relation to an artist (by id)`

Answer (score 0):

Does the following approach work for you?

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tategallery/collection/master/artwork_data.csv' AS line
CREATE(art:Art {id:        line[0], accession_number: line[1], artistId: line[4], title: line[5], medium: line[7],
             creditLine:   line[8], year: line[9], width: line[12], height: line[13], depth: line[14], units: line[15],
             thumbnailUrl: line[18], url: line[19]})
WITH art
MATCH (artist:Artist) WHERE id(artist)=50000
MERGE (artist)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(art);
```

After creating your `Art` node and binding it to the variable `art`, you could match the `artist` by id and link `artist` with `art` afterwards via `MERGE`. The [MERGE clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) ensures that the specified pattern exists in the graph, because either it is already there or it will be created.

Portion of the result:

[image: graph]

Comment: I think `MATCH (artist:Artist{id:line[20]})` is closer to what they are looking for. Also, since the Artist may not have been created yet, and we aren't using merge to create them, creating the relations should be done in a separate run from the Artists (and to avoid merge-merge eager).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS` to load from that file, since it has headers. Your current query would have incorrectly added the header row as an `Art` node. Also, using the header names makes it much easier and less error-prone to write your code (and to read it).

The following query also uses `MERGE` to ensure that every artist (with a unique id) has a unique node. It also does not store `artistId` in the `Art` node, since the `CREATED_BY` relationship will point to the appropriate `Artist`.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tategallery/collection/master/artwork_data.csv' AS r
MERGE (a:Artist {id: r.artistId})
ON CREATE SET a.name = r.artist
CREATE (:Art {
    id: r.id, accession_number: r.accession_number, title: r.title,
    medium: r.medium, creditLine: r.creditLine, year: r.year,
    width: r.width, height: r.height, depth: r.depth, units: r.units,
    thumbnailUrl: r.thumbnailUrl, url: r.url}
  ) - [:CREATED_BY {role: r.artistRole}] -> (a)
```